# Azure bitbucket deployment sync returns 400 bad request

Tags: azure, bitbucket, http-status-code-400

My project on Azure was working fine. It could automatically pull from bitbucket whenever I pushed.

A few days ago, pushed some codes and I saw it is not reflecting new changes. I logged in to Azure and pressed the sync button in Deployment Center, it returns this error:

```
Repository 'SyncSiteRepository' operation failed with System.InvalidOperationException: Failed POST https://waws-prod-am2-***.api.azurewebsites.windows.net/deploy?scmType=BitbucketGit&isAsync=true with The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.AsyncOperation`1.OnEndMethod(IAsyncResult result)
```

I never faced this issue before. I disconnected and reconnected again to bitbucket and checked the repository settings on bitbucket and saw the Azure token on the access tokens list.

I searched a lot on the net and found nothing.

What is wrong?